# Printf() not executing before the "while(1)" loop in C language in Linux

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I noticed something strange with the following code.

```
int main()
{
     printf("Test");      // Section 1 do something here....

     while(1)
     {
           ;
     }
}
```

Section 1 should be executed  first, then the program should get stuck in while loop. 
But the result was that "Test" didn't get printed, but it got stuck in the while loop. I wonder why the code in Section 1 does not get executed?

I ran the code on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS(compiled with the default gcc compiler)

Comment: `printf` is buffered. Add a `\n` to the end to flush the buffered output. That or call `fflush(stdout);` before the loop. If it still doesn't print, we'll re-discuss if GCC produces incorrect code :)

Comment: So many duplicates...  which one to pick?

Comment: @paddy: Pick one of the first.

Comment: So many duplicates - why can nobody search?  And, who in the world upvotes this?

Answer (score 2):

The `stdout` stream is buffered, therefore it will only display what's in the buffer after it reaches a newline. Add :

```
fflush(stdout);
```

after line :

```
printf("Test");
```

See also [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716296/why-does-printf-not-flush-after-the-call-unless-a-newline-is-in-the-format-strin) for other alternatives.

Comment: Please refrain from answering duplicates of duplicates of ... close-vote/flag instead.

Answer (score 0):

This must work:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Test");
    while(1){}
}
```

To compile:

```
 gcc file.c
```

To execute:

```
./a.out
```